# Django has no object attribute named text - but I don't expect it to?

Tags: django

I have the below structure,

When I click on the model name in the admin view, I get the below error. What does this mean?

```
AttributeError at /admin/app/tasksx/
'tasksx' object has no attribute 'text'
Request Method: GET
```

**Admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import tasksx

admin.site.register(tasksx)
```

**Views.py**

```
def create_task(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        creator = request.user
        job_title = 'data engineer'
        skill_name = request.POST.get('skill_name')
        starting = request.POST.get('starting')
        description = request.POST.get('description')
        target_date = request.POST.get('target_date')
    i = tasksx.objects.create(creator=creator, job_title=job_title, skill_name=skill_name,  starting=starting, current=starting, description=description, target_date=target_date)
    messages.success(request, ('Skill created'))
    return redirect('index')
```

**models.py**

```
class tasksx(models.Model):
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=400, default="data")
    creator = models.CharField(max_length=400, default="none")
    skill_name = models.CharField(max_length=400, default="none")
    starting = models.CharField(max_length=400, default="none")
    current = models.CharField(max_length=400, default="none")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=4000000, default="none")
    target_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Comment: Your ```taskx's``` ```__str__``` method is the problem. You are trying to return ```self.text``` when you don't have ```text``` in your model.

Comment: Ahh, so what should I be returning?

Comment: What do you want to see on the admin? The title? So just put ```return self.job_title```.

Comment: How could I see the whole row there?

Comment: What do you mean by whole ```"row"```? You mean all fields?

Comment: Yeah sorry :(...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202164/discussion-between-paolo-and-kikee1222).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding my comments to avoid extended discussion:

In your `tasksx` model's `__str__` method you are trying to return `self.text` when you don't have a `text` field anywhere in the model.

If you want to display the title, modify the method's return to.

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.job_title
```

**Now,** if you want to see all fields in the admin interface, you would need to modify your app's `admin.py`.

***admin.py***

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import tasksx

class Tasksx_Admin(admin.modelAdmin):
    # Add whatever fields you want to display in the admin 
    # in list_diplay tuple.

    list_display = ('job_title', 'creator', 'skill_name', 'starting', 'current', 'description', 'target_date', )

# Register the Taskx_Admin class.

admin.site.register(tasksx, Taskx_Admin)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `tasksx` model you defined:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.text
```

But there is no text property in the model.